# Write command that outputs all JPG images in directory with specific word in file name

Tags: bash, shell, command

How do I write a command that outputs all of the JPEG images in a directory that contain the word “red” to a file named “red_photos.txt”.

Answer (score 1):

Generating the files containing *red* is easy; you can do this with the pattern `*red*`. The tricky part is finding out whether this is a JPEG file or not. You could do something like

```
for f in *red*
do
  if file $f | fgrep -q ' JPEG '
  then
    echo $f >>red_photos.txt
  fi
done
```

Two issues for improvement are left as an exercise (because they are not directly related to the question):

1. If there are really MANY files containing *red*, you might get an "arg list too long" error.
2. If there is no file containing *red*, you might get an error message saying that the wildcard does not match any files (depending on the settings in your bash scripts).

Comment: why not just use `mv` for the renaming of the files?

Comment: Because you would then move all files, not only the ones containing a JPEG picture. Since you can't know from the filename, whether it is a JPEG or not, you have to process each file individually. Admittedly, this is also not 100% safe, since the `file` command can't make more than an educated guess (i.e. it could produce a false positive), but by and large it is reliable.